# Why RichTextBox lose format after appending new String?

Tags: c#

I have aproblem with rich text box string color:

I have the richtexbox that user type a message in it. I mark up each word that exist in my dictionary. I use this code for it:

```
  this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text=this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text.Remove(startCoordinate, endCoordinate - startCoordinate);

  this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionStart = this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text.Length;
 this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionLength = 0;
  this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
  "David",
12, FontStyle.Underline);   
   this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;                                             
   this.inputTextAreaRtb.AppendText(_word);
  this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionColor = this.inputTextAreaRtb.ForeColor;
  this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
   "David",
 12, FontStyle.Regular);
```

But each time if I already marked up a word a loose formatting of words that already formatted.

Any ideas of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text=this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text.Remove(startCoordinate, endCoordinate - startCoordinate);
                ***this.inputTextAreaRtb.Rtf = this.lastRTF;***
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionStart = this.inputTextAreaRtb.Text.Length;
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionLength = 0;
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
                "David",
                12, FontStyle.Underline);   
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;                                             
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.AppendText(_word);
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionColor = this.inputTextAreaRtb.ForeColor;
                this.inputTextAreaRtb.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
                "David",
                12, FontStyle.Regular);
```

I was need only to save the last RTF of RichTextBox before each iteration
Thank`s guys!

Answer (score 4):

When you set `inputTextAreaRtb.Text` in the first line, you're setting a new text that doesn't have any formatting.

Comment: Yes you are right! But what is the alternative solution to this case? Any ideas? I`ve already try the rtf solution downstairs, but it is very complicated, I think there is a more simple solution to this case.

Answer (score 3):

SLaks is correct. To get/set formatted text, you need to access the `Rtf` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx.

Also check out the `SelectedRtf` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf.aspx.